# Building Docker images

Tags: docker, nextflow

I'm trying to build my own docker image using Dockerfile. However, there is something wrong with the Docker image. Here is my dockerfile. At first time, it said successfully built the image; however, some of the package is not working(errors like permission denied and command not found), so I decided to remove all the image and container to rebuild this image. It kept saying using cache instead of reinstall all the packages. When I use this docker, it fails at the very beginning.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
ARG PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget \
    https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && mkdir /root/.conda \
    && bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b \
    && rm -f Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh 
RUN conda --version

RUN conda config --add channels defaults

RUN conda config --add channels bioconda

RUN conda config --add channels conda-forge

RUN conda install -c bioconda bowtie2 fastqc samtools ucsc-bedsort ucsc-bedgraphtobigwig bedtools deeptools homer seacr
```

Comment: I have copied your `Dockerfile` exactly and the image is built with no errors. Please edit the question and add the errors you got

Comment: How are you starting the container?  What are the errors you get?  It seems like this Dockerfile is missing the parts at the end that `COPY` the application code in and declare the standard `CMD` to run; can you make sure you've included the whole thing?

Answer (score 2):

Like others in the comments have stated, your Dockerfile builds correctly and should work as expected using `docker run`. I have some experience building and running Docker containers using [Nextflow](https://www.nextflow.io/), so I thought I'd share my experience building a container that contains all the packages required to run your workflow.

Firstly, consider moving your required packages into an [environment.yml](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file) file. This will help keep all your project's dependencies in one place:

```
name: my-awesome-project
channels:
  - bioconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - bowtie2
  - fastqc
  - samtools
  - ucsc-bedsort
  - ucsc-bedgraphtobigwig
  - bedtools
  - deeptools
  - homer
  - seacr
```

Secondly, consider instead building your Dockerfile from [continuumio/miniconda3](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda3):

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:4.9.2

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y procps \
    && apt-get clean -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY environment.yml /

RUN conda env create -f /environment.yml \
    && conda clean -a

ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/my-awesome-project/bin:$PATH

COPY install_packages.R /
COPY bed_convert.R /
COPY cut_tag_fingerprint_cmd.R /

RUN Rscript install_packages.R
CMD ["Rscript", "bed_convert.R"]
CMD ["Rscript", "cut_tag_fingerprint_cmd.R"]
```

Finally, add profiles for Conda and Docker to your [nextflow.config](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#configuration-file) file. Perhaps something like the following will suffice:

```
process.container = 'my-awesome-project:v1.0'

profiles {
  conda { process.conda = "${baseDir}/environment.yml" }
  docker { docker.enabled = true }
  singularity { singularity.enabled = true }
}
```

Comment: I'm also trying to add some R script into dockerfile. Do you have any idea how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: @Shikan: Use [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) to copy local files to the container's filesystem.

Comment: @Shikan: You may prefer to keep those R scripts in your workflow's 'bin' folder, see: https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/sharing.html#third-party-scripts

Comment: I use COPY to copy local files to container's system like this 'COPY bed_convert.R /' in the Dockerfile, but it's not working.

Comment: @Shikan: That command looks fine to me. What error message do you get? Perhaps try restarting the docker daemon.

Comment: I added my code in upper dockerfile, and did a command 'docker build -t my-image .'. Then I did a test run(nextflow pipeline) using R script, 'Rscript bed_convert.R ${bed} ${sample_id}.stringent.anno.bed', but this process is not working. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Shikan: Not sure - what error message did you get in your `.command.err`, `.command.out` and `.command.log` files? You may need to make sure you have `r-base` (for the `Rscript` command) in your Conda environment file.

Comment: The error massage says command not found.

Comment: Sorry @Shikan, I might need some more details. Do you which command is not found? If it's `Rscript: Comamnd not found`, then you'll need `r-base` in your Conda env. If you're still stuck, please feel free to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66774653/edit) your question with an example Nextflow process and I will take a look if helpful.

Comment: @Steve - I have a related question. I too use conda and environment.yml to build my Nextflow based Docker container. When I use similar tools that you have listed (fastqc, samtools, ... bedtools, etc), the docker image is close to 3GB.

Based on your experience, I wanted to know if you have inputs for reducing the docker image

I have posted similar question here: https://github.com/nf-core/atacseq/issues/153#issue-897706705 and I have tried different ways as listed there to reduce the image size

Thanks in advance.